# Is this right to add window.addEventListener to componentDidMount method in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create new note app with react, and i create modal for adding new note.

for closing modal i add `addEventListener` to `window` in App.js componentDidMount method

```
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const windowOnClick = (event) => {
  if (event.target === modal) {
      modal.classList.toggle('showModal');
      this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
  }
}
window.addEventListener('click', windowOnClick);
```

it's work, but i want to know is this the best practice to do this in react?

Comment: No, this is a common use case. If you want to close the modal when clicking anywhere outside of the modal something like this would be the most straightforward way.

Comment: Tank you for Answering @etarhan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now do this in hooks,

something like :

```
     function toggleModal() {
      const [isOpen, setModalState] = useState(false);

      useEffect(() => {
        const setToggle = () => setModalState(!isOpen);
        window.addEventListener('click', windowOnClick);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('click', windowOnClick);
        };
      });

      return isOpen;
}
```

IMHO this is probably a cleaner way.
As in React is moving away from class based components (see the React docs) and it makes a specific hook to do a specific thing , commonly lots of different stuff is crammed into componentDidMount which , IMHO, mixes up concerns in a lifecycle method. Using a hook makes the logic available to other components as well. See the React docs for more information.

See the React docs for more information.

Comment: What makes this more 'clean' than using a class component and doing the same in componentDidMount lifecycle?

Comment: Yes I am aware, I'm not saying you are incorrect, but you could perhaps add that explanation to your initial answer. Also, how is this answering the current question? Could you at least provide a example using a custom hook based on the current question?